# How to manipulate an output file after reading an input file?

Tags: java, file, input, output

I am making this program that is supposed to read from an input file and then create an output file.

The input File (portlandvip2.txt):

> Court 50
>
> Box 10
>
> Club 25
>
> Rascal Conway 10 Box
>
> Loretta Barrett 3 Court
>
> Loras Tyrell 5 Club
>
> Margaery Tyrell 8 Box
>
> Roslin Frey 2 Box
>
> Sansa Stark 2 Club
>
> Jon Snow 5 Club
>
> Edmure Tully 3 Box
>
> Joffrey Baratheon 20 Court
>
> Stannis Baratheon 4 Club
>
> Jaime Lannister 2 Box
>
> Cersei Lannister 1 Court
>
> Beric Dondarrion 8 Court
>
> Balon Greyjoy 16 Box
>
> Olenna Tyrell 4 Court
>
> Mace Tyrell 5 Box
>
> Tyrion Lannister 2 Club
>
> Sandor Clegane 2 Court
>
> Gregor Clegane 6 Club
>
> Samwell Tarly 3 Club
>
> Petyr Baelish 6 Court

This is an example what the output file is supposed to look like (portland2out.txt):

> Court $50
>
> Box $10
>
> Club $25
>
> Rascal Conway $100.00
>
> Loretta Barrett $150.00

The problem I am having is that all the output file is printing is Petyr Baelish.

This is the program so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.Writer;


public class WebberProject2
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in); 

        File inputScanner = new File("portlandvip2.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("portlandvip2.txt"));
        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String firstName = scanner.next();
            String lastName = scanner.next();

            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("portland2out.txt");

            outputFile.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName); 
            scanner.nextLine();

            inputFile.close();
            outputFile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are opening and closing your output file inside your loop, rewriting a line every time a loop is executed. Take the PrintWriter and its close() method outside the loop. Also, you have other resources that are also being closed in the loop. Try this approach:

```
// ...


Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in); 
File inputScanner = new File("portlandvip2.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("portlandvip2.txt"));
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("portland2out.txt");

while(scanner.hasNext())
{
    String firstName = scanner.next();
    String lastName = scanner.next();

    outputFile.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName); 
    scanner.nextLine();

}
outputFile.close();
inputFile.close();
scanner.close();
// ...
```

Comment: There is also no close of `scanner`, but there is a close of `inputFile`, which is a `Scanner` around `System.in`, which was not opened by this code (and thus, should not be closed by it). Also, the calls to `close` should go in a `finally` block, no?

Comment: @DavidConrad totally agree, I was just focused in the final file. Let me fix my answer

Comment: I have a follow up question, so do i ask it in this post or do i make anew post to ask my follow up question?

Comment: new question would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks incomplete. While loop is not closed. Also you are closing files inside loop which will throw exception. Use following code as base and tweak it as per your requirement. For example, use Scanner method nextInt() for reading number tokens and precede them with $ sign while writing to output file.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class TestScanner{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        PrintWriter outputFile = null;
        try{
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("portlandvip2.txt"));
        outputFile = new PrintWriter("portland2out.txt");
        String firstName, lastName;
        int num = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
             firstName = scanner.next();
             if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                 num = scanner.nextInt();
             }
             lastName = scanner.next();
             outputFile.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName + " $ " + num); 
             scanner.nextLine();

        }
       }catch(IOException e){
           System.out.println("exception:"+e);
       }finally{
           scanner.close();
           outputFile.close();
       }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused, what would that look like? Integer number = scanner.nextInt(); after string lastName?

Comment: If you find my reply useful, please accept my answer. Thanks!